# How can I create a 'SdkTrayManager' without 'OIS::Mouse'?

Tags: ogre

An `OIS::Mouse` is required to create an `SdkTrayManager`:

```
// Constructor in SdkTray.h
SdkTrayManager(const Ogre::String& name, Ogre::RenderWindow* window, 
    OIS::Mouse* mouse, SdkTrayListener* listener = 0) :
```

However, it's only used in the `refreshCursor` method:

```
mCursor->setPosition(mMouse->getMouseState().X.abs, mMouse->getMouseState().Y.abs);
```

Is there was a way to only pass `X.abs` and `Y.abs` to the manager, instead of a pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's what `SdkTrayManager` uses, then that's what `SdkTrayManager` uses. There's no getting around it without actually modifying the code.